# Unable to save list of objects in to database by using JPA repository

Tags: java, jpa

1. While reading csv file data and storing large amount of records into mysql database by using JPA repository save() method. Not able to insert whole data only one record is updating in database. Suggest me where i am ding wrong.

   ```
    private void readFileFromFile(FileUploadDetails fileUploadDetail) throws IOException {

       String filePath = fileUploadDetail.getFilePath();
       try {
           FileReader filereader = new FileReader(filePath);
           CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(filereader).withSkipLines(1).build();
           List<String[]> nextRecord;
           List<FileAnnualEnterpriseSurveyLog> fileAnnualEnterpriseSurveyLog = new ArrayList<>();
           FileAnnualEnterpriseSurveyLog fileAESurveyLogVo = new FileAnnualEnterpriseSurveyLog();
           // we are going to read data line by line

           List<String[]> allData = csvReader.readAll();
           int count = 0;
           for (String[] cell : allData) {
               fileAESurveyLogVo.setYear(cell[0].toString());
               fileAESurveyLogVo.setIndustryAggregationNZSIOC(cell[1].toString());
               fileAESurveyLogVo.setIndustryCodeNZSIOC(cell[2].toString());
               fileAESurveyLogVo.setIndustryNameNZSIOC(cell[3].toString());
               fileAESurveyLogVo.setUnits(cell[4].toString());
               fileAESurveyLogVo.setVariableCode(cell[5].toString());
               fileAESurveyLogVo.setVariableName(cell[6].toString());
               fileAESurveyLogVo.setVariableCategory(cell[7].toString());
               fileAESurveyLogVo.setValue(cell[8].toString());
               fileAESurveyLogVo.setIndustryCodeANZSIC06(cell[9].toString());
               fileAnnualEnterpriseSurveyLog.add(fileAESurveyLogVo);
               // fileAnnualEnterpriseSurveyRepository.save(fileAESurveyLogVo);
               // fileAnnualEnterpriseSurveyRepository.
               System.out.println(count);
               count++;
           }
           System.out.println(fileAnnualEnterpriseSurveyLog.size()); // 277777

           for (FileAnnualEnterpriseSurveyLog file : fileAnnualEnterpriseSurveyLog) {

               fileAnnualEnterpriseSurveyRepository.save(file);

           }

       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();

       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and fix the formatting of the code in your post.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have inserted the first object, you are updating always the same. You should create a new element at each iteration.

```
for (String[] cell : allData) {
    fileAESurveyLogVo = new FileAnnualEnterpriseSurveyLog();
    fileAESurveyLogVo.setYear(cell[0].toString());
    fileAESurveyLogVo.setIndustryAggregationNZSIOC(cell[1].toString());
    ... etc ...
}
```